# How do I hide the left nav bar (including space) in MOSS 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am able to remove the left nav bar with this code:

```
.ms-nav {width: 0px;}
.ms-navframe {display:none;}
.ms-quicklaunchouter{width:0px;}
.ms-recyclebin {display:none;}
.ms-TitleAreaFrame {display:none;}
.ms-titlearealeft {display:none;}
.ms-titlearea {display:none;}
.ms-pagetitle {display:none;}
```

but it adds a left space that takes up half of the page to my edit/create/view all content pages/check-in/etc.  I was able to fix this with a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP), but I would like to know if there is a way to do this in a .css file to use throughout the entire site.  I have over 100 pages and would rather not have to add a CEWP to each page.

Thanks For The Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
.ms-leftareacell {background-color:#D6E8FF;}
.ms-nav {display:none;}
```

And yes, you can create a CSS file and upload it to Style Library. Then go into Site Settings > Master Page (under Look and Feel) and have Alternate CSS URL point to your CSS file in the Style Library.

Comment: Still have the same problem, here's a screenshot of it: http://www.imageupload.org/share.php?id=893D_4C6AEDDB

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution is good, but you can get a better result like this:

```
.ms-nav { display:none; }
.ms-leftareacell {
          background-color: #83B0EC;
          background-image: url("/_layouts/images/navshape.jpg");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: -143px 0px;
}
```